# Что не так с циклом for по списку?

Tags: python

Почему при одинаковых элементах списка не выводятся их индексы?

```
lst = list('aaaba')
print(lst)

for lettr in lst:
    print(lst.index(lettr), lettr)
```

Вывод получаем такой:
['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']
0 a
0 a
2 b
0 a

Если цикл все-таки перебрал и вывел элементы списка, почему не вывел их индексы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что метод `index` ищет **первое** вхождение элемента в список. Т.е. сколько бы букв `'a'` у вас в списке ни было, сколько бы раз вы не вызывали метод `index` всегда получите один и тот же ответ (в вашем случае `0`).
Если вы хотите пробежаться по парам `(element, index)` - используйте `enumerate`:

```
for index, letter in enumerate(lst):
    print(index, letter)
```